# Why is the word 'resuscitation' preferred over 'revival' or 'resurrection' in medical contexts?

Tags: synonyms, medical

this has been boggling me for a long time now. I never heard of what doctors do in intensive care as 'revival', 'bringing up the dead' or something else. If medical staff of any kind is involved, it will always be 'resuscitate'.

I have tried to consult the AMA Manual of Style, but their sign-up process is non-functional, facing technical issues. Browsing dictionaries was no use either, they all list these words as synonyms.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a very convincing answer to your question. Still, bear in mind that the duration of a word in a given language, how it evolves or doesn't evolve from its actual meaning overtime and its currency in certain spheres are a few factors that influence its usage in one or the other domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surmise that this is specifically to *preclude* any religious or mythological overtones to their work.

Comment: Why does 'resuscitation' fit these criteria?

Comment: One *doesn't* typically see dozens or hundreds of references to *"The Resuscitation"* in commonly-accessed in English religious texts, whereas **"The Resurrection"** *is* a commonly-used referent to the Christian dogma about the rebirth of their canonical messiah post mortem, and the word "revival" in both England and the United States (most commonly the antebellum US South) has been used to describe an outdoor Christian gathering whose primary stated purpose is to exhort a greater religious fervour in the participants, implicitly assuming their fervour to have flagged; hence revival.